# Agregar texto informativo dentro de un data-table

Tags: javascript

Desearía saber cómo colocar un texto informativo que al pasar el mouse por ese texto, resalte un mensaje para que el usuario pueda observar, soy un poco nuevo en programación.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/evquD.png

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a el documento [ask], te sugerimos editar tu pregunta y agregar lo que has tratado o investigado. No olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio para conocer su funcionamiento básico, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo usar ToolTip que tambien es de bootstrap, aca te dejo la documentacion: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/, y aca un pequeño ejemplo:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<br>
&nbsp; &nbsp; <span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mensaje">Pandreac</span>

</html>
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba !!! excelente :D